# Conflict among three exit strategies in TradingView

Tags: pine-script

I set up three exit strategies as quoted below. The first one is the main exit strategy to be used. The second one is to maximize profit after breakthrough. The third one is for cut loss only.

```
1.    strategy.close( "Long",when = Close_Condition == true and is_breakthrough == false)  // main exit strategy
2.    strategy.exit("CP","Long", stop = Cut_Profit, when = is_breakthrough == true)  // maximize profit strategy
3.    strategy.exit("CL","Long", stop = Stop_Price)  // cut loss strategy
```

However, when the entire strategy is executed, the** Cut Loss Strategy** is always considered as the only exit strategy. Even if the criteria of **Strategy 1 or Strategy 2** is fulfilled, the program ignored both strategies and no action is taken by the program (cannot sell the stock).

If **Cut Loss Strategy** is deleted, **Strategy 1 & Strategy 2** functioned normally and an expected result is showed.

So how to make the three exit strategies function well? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you have the `CL` exit always at the maket, so you can't send one more order to close the same position. What you should do it so use the `strategy.cancel` function to cancel the previos order:

```
// ...some script's logic...
if is_breakthrough
    strategy.cancel("CL") // cancel sent order
    strategy.exit("CP","Long", stop = Cut_Profit) opened a new order on position's close
strategy.exit("CL","Long", stop = Stop_Price)
```

then it should work